# Insertion in Nested Tables on Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am a new learner of PL/SQL databases,A kind of exercise given to apply database on apex.oracle.com with given sequence.Then I have created tables but when it comes to fill tables with the insertion code as follows,Application has given error,Would you mind if I need your assistance

Thanks in Advance,

```
CREATE TYPE TEMPORAL_VARCHAR AS OBJECT (

VALID_TIME_LOWER_BOUND DATE,

VALID_TIME_UPPER_BOUND DATE,

VALUE_PART VARCHAR2(50)
 );

CREATE TYPE TEMPORAL_NUMBER AS OBJECT (

VALID_TIME_LOWER_BOUND DATE,

VALID_TIME_UPPER_BOUND DATE,

VALUE_PART NUMBER );
```

Time-related attributeshave defined with the code as follows;

```
CREATE TYPE NAME_TYPE AS TABLE OF TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;

CREATE TYPE ADDRESS_TYPE AS TABLE OF TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;

CREATE TYPE DEPARTMENT_TYPE AS TABLE OF TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;

CREATE TYPE MANAGER_TYPE AS TABLE OF TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;

CREATE TYPE SALARY_TYPE AS TABLE OF TEMPORAL_NUMBER;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
SSN NUMBER primary key,

 NAME NAME_TYPE,

 ADDRESS ADDRESS_TYPE ,

 BIRTH_DATE DATE,

MANAGER MANAGER_TYPE ,

 DEPARTMENT DEPARTMENT_TYPE,

 SALARY SALARY_TYPE

)

NESTED TABLE NAME STORE AS NAME_TABLE,

NESTED TABLE ADDRESS STORE AS ADDRESS_TABLE,

NESTED TABLE MANAGER STORE AS MANAGER_TABLE,

NESTED TABLE DEPARTMENT STORE AS DEPARTMENT_TABLE,

NESTED TABLE SALARY STORE AS SALARY_TABLE

;
```

And the insertion that I am inteded to do

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
(101,

NAME(TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('23.11.2005','12.31.9999','James Brown')),

ADDRESS(TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('23.11.2005','12.31.9999','BUCA, IZMIR')),

'23.10.1986',

MANAGER(TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('23.11.2005','12.31.9999','Mike White')),

DEPARTMENT(TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('23.11.2005','12.31.9999','DEPT_ID05')),

SALARY(TEMPORAL_NUMBER('23.11.2005',’12.31.9999’, 250000))
);
```

And the error message I recieved is :

**ORA-00904: "SALARY": invalid identifier**

Comment: Please include the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces before `_` here

```
CREATE TYPE MANAGER _TYPE AS TABLE OF TEMPORAL_VARCHAR;

CREATE TYPE SALARY _TYPE AS TABLE OF TEMPORAL_NUMBER;

DEPARTMENT DEPARTMENT _TYPE
```

A comma is missing after DEPARTMENT _TYPE

Comment: Yes I have created tables but when it comes to insertion,I am encountering the error

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
'alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD.MM.YYYY';'
----------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
(101,
NAME_TYPE(TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('23.10.1986','09.09.9999','James Brown')),
ADDRESS_TYPE(TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('15.12.2009','09.09.9999','BUCA')),
'23.10.1986',
MANAGER_TYPE(TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('24.05.2008','09.09.9999','Mike White')),
DEPARTMENT_TYPE(TEMPORAL_VARCHAR('03.01.2012','09.09.9999','DEPT_ID05')),
SALARY_TYPE(TEMPORAL_NUMBER('01.01.2003','09.09.9999', 3200))
);
```